# Best way to provide whether groups of control variables are included in the model or not

Tags: r, modelsummary

I am using the modelsummary package to format my regression tables. I would now like to format my tables so that there is one row which indicates whether groups of control variables are included in the model or not. This would be similar to Stata esttab:

```
clear
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/nlsw88b.dta

eststo model1: reg wage occupation
eststo model2: reg wage occupation age race married
eststo model3: reg wage occupation age race married industry union

esttab model1 model2 model3 using Tables.rtf, replace indicate("Individual controls = age race married" "Industry controls = industry union")
```

The result in Stata looks like this:
[![Group of controls][1]].

I know I could use the add_rows command to do it manually. Since I will run a lot of models, I would like to automate it. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmoK4.png

Comment: The easiest way would be to omit the coefficients and use the `add_rows` argument. See `?modelsummary` and https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#add_rows

Comment: Thank you Vincent. Yeah, that was what I had indeed suspected! :)